# ObjectManager The method createQuery() does not seem to exist

Tags: php, symfony

I have class like this which works and returns feedbacks from the database

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Handler;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class FeedbackHandler implements FeedbackHandlerInterface
{
    private $em;
    private $entityClass;
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $mr, $entityClass)
    {
        $this->em = $mr->getManager();
        $this->entityClass = $entityClass;
        $this->repository = $this->em->getRepository($this->entityClass);
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->repository->find($id);
    }

    public function all($limit = 50, $offset = 0)
    {

        $feedbacks = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT f FROM AcmeAcmeBundle:Feedback f")
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getResult();

        return array( "feedback" => $feedbacks );
    }

}
```

however when I submit code to scrutinizer-ci.com it reports that

> The method createQuery() does not seem to exist on
>   object

same with PhpStorm, it displays warning at this line. Is there an approach to fix this issue?

Comment: *"works and returns feedbacks from the database"* if it works why do you care about *scrutinizer-ci.com* or *PhpStorm* (maybe they are not configured for Symdony services)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `@var` **phpdoc** comment for the `$em` variable ...

... or (even better) `@return` to `ManagerRegistry`'s `getManager()` method.

Then PHPStorm / scrutinizer-ci will both know of which type `$em` is and that it has a `createQuery()` method.

This is a good practice in general and will enable autocompletion in PHPStorm, too.

**example:**

```
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
private $em;
```

... or ...

```
class ManagerRegistry 
{

   /**
    * ...
    *
    * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */ 
    public function getManager()
    { 
        // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however when I add @var comment it shows: It seems like $mr->getManager() of type object<Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager> is incompatible with the declared type object<Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager> of property $em

Comment: My answer totally solves your initial problem. please open a new question for your new issue. short hint: your new error obviously occurs because you return i.e. a `DocumentManager` instance instead of `EntityManger` in your setup. Make sure the doc domments match the actual instances.